# can i build and distribute multiple devices that use only one provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, profile, provisioning

I have a question

Can i build and distribute a app by different mac device by use only one provisioning profile?

I have some ios devices and have workmates.

My workmate do build.
I distribute to ad hoc or appstore.
we have different mac device.
so a provisioning profile is used to development
another provisioning profile is used to distribute (another device)

the point is i want to use only one provisioning profile.

if so, how?!

Answer (score 1):

You need a provisioning profile for each Mac you wish to distribute from (ad hoc or app store).  You can use as many computers as you'd like to write the code or test in the simulator, but with only one provisioning profile, I believe you can only build to devices or build for App Store from a single Mac.